# Member function of inherited class won't change inherited base class variable

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, public

So I have a base class with the following header file:

```
#ifndef ODESolver_H
#define ODESolver_H
#endif
#include "DoublePendulum.h"

class ODESolver
{
public: 
    ODESolver(DoublePendulum &);
    virtual void Predict(const double &)=0;
    DoublePendulum DP;
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "ODESolver.h"
#include <iomanip>

ODESolver::ODESolver(DoublePendulum &DPRef) :DP(DPRef)
{}
```

And a class that inherits from it:

```
#ifndef ODEEuler_H
#define ODEEuler_H
#endif

#include "ODESolver.h"

class ODEEuler : public ODESolver
{
public:
    ODEEuler(DoublePendulum &);
    void Predict(const double &);
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "ODEEuler.h"

ODEEuler::ODEEuler (DoublePendulum &DPRef) :ODESolver(DPRef)
{}

void ODEEuler::Predict(const double &dt=0.005)
{
    DP=DP+DP.Derivate()*dt;
    cout << DP.getUp().getTheta() << endl;
}
```

The problem is that in the above implementation, `DP=DP+DP.Derivate()*dt;` won't do anything. I have no clue how this is possible. I have checked if the `.Derivate()` member function works and it actually returns the correct values/object. On top of that, it doesn't matter what I do there e.g. `DP=DoublePendulum RandomObject(1,2,3,4)` will still keep DP the same. Any ideas? I hope I provided enough information...

Also the implementation and declaration of DoublePendulum etc:

http://pastebin.com/ny3pU8aR

Comment: Is it defined the operator+ between DP and (DP.Derivate()*dt) to do what you expect to do?

Comment: Both DP and DP.Derivate are objects of the DoublePendulum class, for which I overloaded the + operator. I have checked this for adding random objects. On top of that, I wrote the following on that line: 

DoublePendulum Result=DP+DP.Derivate()*dt 

which gave the correct values.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `DoublePendulum`.. Want to see what operators are defined in it.

Comment: On an unrelated note: Your #include guard is wrong: The `#endif` must be at the end of the file. As it is now, it achieves nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assignment operator

```
DoublePendulum DoublePendulum::operator= (DoublePendulum &DoublePendulumA)
{
        return DoublePendulum (DoublePendulumA);
}
```

creates a new value, but does not really assign anyting to the left-hand-side of the assignment. That's why it doesn't change!

The standard form of assignment looks like

```
DoublePendulum& DoublePendulum::operator= (const DoublePendulum& DoublePendulumA)
{
    // assign to members of this object

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a god among men. You just saved me several days of work.

I thought I had found a "shortcut" in C++ to implement the copy assignment operator, apparently I didn't...